# bootstrap dropdown menu Two links on same horizontal row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to make drop down menus. One of the options I would like to have is two links on the same horizontal row in a dropdown menu. How would I achieve this?

```
<div class = "navbar">
<div class = "navbar-inner">

<li class = "dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown Button
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>

    <ul class = "dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
        <li><a href="#">On First Row</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">On Second Row</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">On Third Row</a><a href="#">Also On Third Row</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with how you have it? That should put them on the same row.

Comment: @brbcoding Hmm...after inspecting the element of 'On Third Row' it looks like Bootstrap targets links with `dropdown-menu a` in CSS that sets the `display: Block` and has `white space: nowrap`. After manually overriding to `inline-block`, turning off `white space` and setting width = 50% I was able to get the two links side-by-side...However would you know of a way to get them to expand the size of the container? I think it's a bit odd that the container 'dropdown-menu' is a fixed width and doesn't auto resize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solved Code is here >>>>> [**two links in one dropdown list item**](http://jsfiddle.net/3CwzH/3/)

html

---

```
    <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown Button
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">On First Row</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">On Second Row</a>
                </li>
                <li class="hz"><a href="#">On Third Row</a><a href="#">Also On Third Row</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

---

```
.open> ul>li.hz{
    display: inline-flex !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with eirenaios answer:

When the dropdown is contained within a collapsible navbar, multiple `<li>` will be shown on one line (until it wraps to the next line) when the navbar is collapsed. This looks very ugly and confusing.

Here is the solution, based on eirenaios answer, but works also for toggled (collapsible) navbars with dropdowns:

https://plnkr.co/edit/JnsvKGiBokrI1frxC11P?p=preview

---

**EDIT:**

Additional CSS rule:

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
    display: table-caption;
}
```

---

HTML (mostly the same as the original, but surrounded by `.navbar-collapse` and added `.navbar-header` with a hamburger menu button to open the collapsed menu):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar0">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <!-- toggled content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar0">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown Menu A <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="hz">
            <a href="#">Item A1 left</a>
            <a href="#">Item A1 right</a>
          </li>
          <li class="hz">
            <a href="#">Item A2 left</a>
            <a href="#">Item A2 right</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Single item A3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="hz">
            <a href="#">Item A3 left</a>
            <a href="#">Item A3 right</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your answer (should provide context for any included links)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer]. In this case you mention that another answer is incorrect but you don't provide any explanation as to what you modified. If the link becomes unavailable the answer becomes irrelevant.

Comment: thank you hoss, I've just edited my post with the missing information.