# Insert link on same line as dropdown menu item in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want a dropdown menu item to have a separate link to a "What's this?" option. A previous question looked at this for bootstrap3, which uses html list syntax for dropdowns (`<li>` and such):
[bootstrap dropdown menu Two links on same horizontal row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844533/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-two-links-on-same-horizontal-row)

The syntax for dropdown menus is different now (slightly simplified):

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn"> Dropdown button</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, say I want to insert another link to the right of one of the dropdown menu items (e.g., Action 2)?

```
<a href = "#">What's this?</a>
```

This image shows what I am after:

[image]

Note I am not trying to insert an additional dropdown menu inside this dropdown item: I just want a simple link to the right of dropdown item 2.

When I try to insert this *after* Action 2, it just becomes a separate line. Obviously I can't nest it inside of the anchor (I tried it just for fun and the link/text appears but does nothing, as expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `dropdown-item` a DIV and put 2 links inside it...

https://www.codeply.com/go/MzI65YRv7Q

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <a class="text-dark" href="#1">Action 2</a>
        <a class="" href="#2">[what's this?]</a>
    </div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great answer: elegant and simple. I would suggest one tweak to your answer, that I put in my code: the main item text becomes underlined with hover, which is not standard behavior for a dropdown item; I just added the `style = "text-decoration:none;"`, so now it matches the behavior of all the other items perfectly!  (I also changed class to `text-white` but that is a little detail that will depend on your particular bs style everyone obviously will need to figure that out on their own :).